# dataframe drop_duplicates with subset of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For the subset argument i want to specify the first n-1 columns. How'll I do that?

For example: in the following dataset

```
   0   1  2   3   4  5   6
0  0  12  1  99  23  2  75
1  0  12  1  99  23  2  66
2  5  12  1  99  23  2  66
```

I want the result to be 1st and 3 rd row only:

```
   0   1  2   3   4  5   6
0  0  12  1  99  23  2  75
1  5  12  1  99  23  2  66
```

If I do something like the following I get error:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=[0:df.shape[1]-1],keep='first',inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can using `duplicated`

```
df[~df.iloc[:,:-1].duplicated()]
Out[53]: 
   0   1  2   3   4  5   6
0  0  12  1  99  23  2  75
2  5  12  1  99  23  2  66
```

Answer (score 2):

You're close, but you can index on the column names, it's easier.

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=df.columns[:-1], keep='first')

   0   1  2   3   4  5   6
0  0  12  1  99  23  2  75
2  5  12  1  99  23  2  66
```

Where,

```
df.columns[1:].tolist()
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

This generalises to any dataFrame regardless of what its column names are.

Comment: @jpp It is not (here), but always necessary inside a groupby. I do it for consistency.